# Cannot see colors in LaTeX output - lstlistings

Tags: listings, code

Can you give me some help? In the following I only see black text, although I set lots of things with different colors... Why isn't this working?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
%Packages
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point (with d instead of p{}, l, r, c, etc.)
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
```

...

```
\begin{lstlisting}
void LUdecomposition3   (float*, float*, float*, int);
//receives as arguments 3 arrays of doubles with the diagonals'
//coefficients the values pointed to are changed within this
// method so that they can be used in the following method : LUsolve3


void LUsolve3       (float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, int);
//
\end{lstlisting}
```

Sorry for giving so much things that probably doesn't matter, but as I don't know where the error is...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: To what language does the example code you posted language belong to?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you didn't specify the language to be used so there's no way for the package to recognize which strings to treat as keywords, which as comments, etc. As soon as you specify the proper language (either a predefined one (see Table 1 in the package documentation) or a user-defined one (also, refer to the package documentation)), the color applies appropriately.

I assumed below that your code corresponded to `C++` just for the example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
%Packages
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point (with d instead of p{}, l, r, c, etc.)
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset{
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,
    columns=fullflexible,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
void LUdecomposition3   (float*, float*, float*, int);
//receives as arguments 3 arrays of doubles with the diagonals'
//coefficients the values pointed to are changed within this
// method so that they can be used in the following method : LUsolve3


void LUsolve3       (float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, int);
//
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Some suggestions:

- Code is usually typeset using a mono-spaced font, so I added `\ttfamily` to the `basicstyle` key specification.
- Your current font size (`\footnotesize`) seems to be too small. Perhaps consider changing to `\small`.